# Google Play Consoleの「統計情報」や「売上レポート」の情報をpythonで自動で取得したい

Tags: python, android, google-play-console

現在、Androidアプリを公開していて、結果を自動取得して確認したいと思います。
アプリのインストール数、売上などはGoogle Play Console画面で確認できることはわかっています。

私は、Google Play Consoleの「統計情報(獲得ユーザー数)」や「売上レポート」の情報をpythonで自動で取得したいと考えています。

自動取得には、GoogleのAPIを利用するのでは？と思ってます。
Googleには、たくさんのAPIがありますが、「統計情報(獲得ユーザー数)」や「売上レポート」
の情報を取得するのはどれを使うのかわかっていません。

「Google Play Developer API」のような気がしましたが、apkファイルをアップロードしたりするものだとわかりました。

Google Play Consoleの「統計情報(獲得ユーザー数)」や「売上レポート」の情報をプログラミングを使って取得する方法が分かる人がいましたら教えて下さい。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは。Google Playの集計レポートはCSVファイル形式でダウンロードできます。

画面からダウンロードする他、サービスアカウントを利用してクラウドストレージに
Pythonなどのプログラム言語を利用してダウンロードすることもできますのでおためしください

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=ja

#### 付記

説明不足でしたので付記させていただきます。リンク先のページの項「Google Cloud Storage からレポートをダウンロードする」をご確認ください。

gsutilを経由してダウンロードする方法と、Play Storeにサービスアカウントと呼ばれる特殊なアカウントを追加してプログラムからダウンロードする方法の二つがあります。どちらの方法をとっても、日次単位のバッチプログラムで加工処理を行うことができると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
大変助かります。

念の為、確認させてください。
Google Playの集計レポートは、プログラムから直接取ることはできなく、一旦、クラウドのストレージに保存する必要があるという認識でよろしいですか？

Comment: こんにちは。
頂いたリンクを見てやっと理解しました。

Google Cloud Storageに集計レポートが(自動的に？)書き出されるので、それをpythonで取得するということですね。

このあと、試してみます。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: はい、gsutilを経由してダウンロードする方法と、Play Storeにサービスアカウントと呼ばれる特殊なアカウントを追加してプログラムからダウンロードする方法の二つがあります。どちらの方法をとっても、日次単位のバッチプログラムで加工処理を行うことができると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。gsutilツールにてダウンロードできました。大変助かります。

Comment: 問題が解決したようでよかったです。回答済みにチェックいただければありがたく思います。